HIVE: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute

I am trying to run Hive on my Windows 10 laptop.
I have followed all the steps correctly and Downloaded Hadoop, Hive, Derby. The environment variables are set correctly.
Started by running start-dfs and start-yarn. (with Admin permissions)
Then in new termial,started a server -h 0.0.0.0.
And again in a new terminal ran "hive" command when I came across this error. (All the terminals have admin permissions).
This is the full error. Ignore the bindings warnings.

C:\hive\bin>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/hadoop-3.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:358)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:496)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:136)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(TempFileHelper.java:173)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Files.java:950)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:245)


I guess it's something realted to POSIX not compatible with Windows.
There are many similar questions but none of them are related to Hive.
Any help is appriciated. Thanks!


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
